# ASP.NET SiteMap control invalid XHTML -title contains &

Tags: asp.net, validation, xhtml, sitemap, web-controls

I'm using the .SiteMap file and Sitemap control to create a sitemap on a page. The title of the page in the Web.sitemap is: "Out & About".

When the page renders, the ampersand is shown as an & (Out & About) in the source, this obviously then causes validation errors.

Any ideas how I can force good ol' .net sitemap to encode the ampersand as I entered it into the title.

As usual, thanks for any help.
peteski

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode your text first, this will emit the appropriate entities (in this case "`&amps;`").

Comment: I don't see how I can do this as the .SiteMap file is XML.

Comment: You an manually add an extra level of encoding in your file: "&amps;amps;"

Comment: Using "&amp;amp;" works inside of the web.sitemap file.  Really dumb that MS removes the encoding.  A single &amp; should work if they were doing it correctly.